# How to execute the SELECT query with % sign with positional parameters in SQLite Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to run SQL select query like following.

```
books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn LIKE '{%:isbn%}' or title LIKE '{%:title%}' or author LIKE '{%author%}'", {"isbn": isbn, "title" : title, "author": author}).fetchall()
```

But it is giving me error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "212"

```
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn LIKE '{%'212'%}' or title LIK...
[SQL: SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn LIKE '{%%%(isbn)s%%}' or title LIKE '{%%%(title)s%%}' 
or author LIKE '{%%author%%}']
[parameters: {'isbn': '212', 'title': 'cro'}]
```

I am new to this framework. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So, the problem was % did not append in the query, you need to append it before and then run the query.

Answer (score 0):

you try to separate the query into a string and args in another ?

somenthing like this

```
`def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
rv = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
```

`

and the query string 'LIKE = ?'

Comment: I tried this but, it give me error of AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: the args receive a tuple, and you trying  pass a dict {'isbn': '212', 'title': 'cro'}; remove the keys, and place the args in order